# How to make search results clickable

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, click

I have created a database app, where the user can search for a film. The app will then return the results of this search in a ScrollView. I then want these search results to be clickable, which will lead to another page to display full details of the film selected. What is the best way to do this?

```
public void search(View v){
    EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    String searchresult = "%" + search.getText().toString() + "%";
    db = new DbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    String[] tblColumns = {"*"};
    String where = "film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?";
    String[] args = {searchresult, searchresult, searchresult, searchresult};
    Cursor results = db.query("FILMTABLE", tblColumns, where, args, null, null, null);
    film(results);
}

public void film (Cursor c){

    c.moveToFirst();
    int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("film");
    int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    String title = c.getString(titleIndex);
    int filmID = c.getInt(idIndex);

    TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txt.setId(filmID);
    txt.setText(title);
    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt.setTextSize(15);

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrolLView);
    scrollView.addView(txt);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your search result in arraylist and use the listview for showing the result. Then implement listview.setOnItemClickListner.

Follow this  : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Every widget in Android is a clickable object. You can format the results however you like, likely in a ListView and set each one's `onClick` attribute to be whatever function in Java you need executed when clicked. If they all operate the same, you can just put a click listener on the entire list. If they are intended to operate differently (the more likely case) you can individually assign methods to each element in the list using the above.